# How can I concatenate in a PHP Function?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table that I am drawing information on that has a few fields. The two fields in particular that I need concatenated are Firstname and Surname but I cannot add another column to the actual table.

Is it possible to edit my PHP function to concatenate it for me when I call on it?

Here is my PHP function

```
public function getCustomerinfoByCompanyID($itemID) {

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM $this->tablename where CompanyID=?");
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $itemID);        
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    $rows = array();

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->CustID, $row->CompanyID, $row->FirstName, $row->Surname, $row->CellNo, $row->Email);

    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
      $rows[] = $row;
      $row = new stdClass();
      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->CustID, $row->CompanyID, $row->FirstName, $row->Surname, $row->CellNo, $row->Email);
    }

    mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
    mysqli_close($this->connection);

    return $rows;
}
```

Comment: This is only the database code. But you talk about the output. Please post the output code instead.

Comment: AHHH quit using the procedural API its so revolting! ;-)

Comment: @hakre: Well he could add a property to the `stdObject`'s hes hydrating instead of handling it in the view directly.

Comment: @prodigitalson: Sure, but I think [@Camilo Lizarazo's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9491678/367456) is even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your query as

```
SELECT *,CONCAT(FirstName,' ',Surname) as FullName FROM $this->tablename where CompanyID=?
```

then you change

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->CustID, $row->CompanyID, $row->FirstName, $row->Surname, $row->CellNo, $row->Email);
```

to something like

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->CustID, $row->CompanyID, $row->FullName, $row->CellNo, $row->Email);
```

And there you have it on one column

Comment: Big help, thanks Camilo. Unfortunately, while it works, the place I am using it in, IE Adobe Flex, it does not allow me to then assign the FullName as my output render in my Spinner List. But I will carry on experimenting until I get it right.

Comment: Well, i dont know wich id or keyword is using your Flex script but u can use anything to match it, if u are usig FirstName, then u may use sql query as 'SELECT CustID,CompanyID, CONCAT(FirstName,' ',Surname) as FirstName,CellNo,Email FROM $this->tablename where CompanyID=?' this way you only have one FirstName column with both fields in it and you will be passing same id to Flex

Comment: I came right Camilo :) It was a stupid mistake on my part. Your code worked perfectly :)